# How to use solid border css style

Tags: html, css, border

As Elastic watches don't allow `<style>`, I need to use `<th style=\"...\">` format. But somehow I can't get my solid borders to work properly.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <table style=\"font-family:'TrebuchetMS',Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;background-color:#D8E5E8;border-collapse:collapse;width:100%;max-width:700px;min-width:100px;text-align:center;border:2px solid #ddd;\">
      <tr>
        <th style=\"font-size:12pt;background-color:#1A94BD;color:white;height:20px;padding:2px;vertical-align:middle;border:2pxsolid#ddd;\">Timestamp</th>
        <th style=\"font-size:12pt;background-color:#1A94BD;color:white;height:20px;padding:2px;vertical-align:middle;border:2pxsolid#ddd;\">User</th>
        <th style=\"font-size:12pt;background-color:#1A94BD;color:white;height:20px;padding:2px;vertical-align:middle;border:2pxsolid#ddd;\">Event Type</th>
        <th style=\"font-size:12pt;background-color:#1A94BD;color:white;height:20px;padding:2px;vertical-align:middle;border:2pxsolid#ddd;\">Node Name</th>
        <th style=\"font-size:12pt;background-color:#1A94BD;color:white;height:20px;padding:2px;vertical-align:middle;border:2pxsolid#ddd;\">Uri</th>
      </tr>
      {{#ctx.payload.list}}
      <tr>
        <td style=\"font-size:10pt;height:20px;padding:2px;vertical-align:middle;border:2px solid #ddd;\">{{be_time}}</td>
        <td style=\"font-size:10pt;height:20px;padding:2px;vertical-align:middle;border:2px solid #ddd;\">{{user}}</td>
        <td style=\"font-size:10pt;height:20px;padding:2px;vertical-align:middle;border:2px solid #ddd;\">{{event_type}}</td>
        <td style=\"font-size:10pt;height:20px;padding:2px;vertical-align:middle;border:2px solid #ddd;\">{{node_name}}</td>
        <td style=\"font-size:10pt;height:20px;padding:2px;vertical-align:middle;border:2px solid #ddd;\">{{uri}}</td>
      </tr>
      {{/ctx.payload.list}}
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

How do I need to format `'border:2px solid #ddd;'` so I can get a nice border. When I use `<style>` I can get it working like I want it:

```
<style>table{font-family:'TrebuchetMS',Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;background-color:#D8E5E8;border-collapse:collapse;width:100%;max-width:700px;min-width:100px;text-align:center;}table,th,td{border:2px solid #ddd;}th,td{height:20px;padding:2px;vertical-align:middle;}td{font-size:10pt;}th{font-size:12pt;background-color:#1A94BD;color:white;}</style>
```

But whatever I try in `style=\"..`:
`'border:2px solid #ddd;'`
`'border:2pxsolid#ddd;'`
No border is appearing

Comment: split it like this `border-style:...;border-color:...;border-width:...`

Comment: Aaah yes that works, if you make an answer of this, I'll happily accept it. tx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have trouble with the shorthand version of border you can split it:

So `border:2px solid #ddd;` become  `border-style:solid;border-color:#ddd;border-width:2px`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border